# All $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ such that center of mass of the function (uniform density) is on its graph

Tags: calculus, functions, physics

So, as the title describes, I'm trying to find a way to express all $y=f(x)$ differentiable on $[0,1]$ such that the center of mass of the function, assuming it has uniform density, will be a point on the graph of the function. Some obvious examples are $y=0.5$ or $y=x$.

What I tried to do was say that

$$x_{c.m.} = \frac{1}{L} \int_0^1  x\sqrt{1+f'(x)^{2}}dx$$

and

$$y_{c.m.} = \frac{1}{L} \int_0^1  f(x)\sqrt{1+f'(x)^{2}}dx$$

where

$$L= \int_0^1  \sqrt{1+f'(x)^{2}}$$

so I guess my question could also be stated:

Describe all $f(x)$ such that

$$f(\frac{1}{L} \int_0^1  x\sqrt{1+f'(x)^{2}}dx) = \frac{1}{L} \int_0^1  f(x)\sqrt{1+f'(x)^{2}}dx$$

or

$$f(\frac{1}{\int_0^1  \sqrt{1+f'(x)^{2}}dx} \int_0^1  x\sqrt{1+f'(x)^{2}}dx) = \frac{1}{\int_0^1  \sqrt{1+f'(x)^{2}}dx} \int_0^1  f(x)\sqrt{1+f'(x)^{2}}dx$$

Comment: "the center of mass of the line" ... *what* line?

Comment: @GregMartin the line is f(x) from x ∈ [0,1]

Comment: ah, do you mean the graph of $y=f(x)$?

Comment: If so, then there are lots of examples: $f(x) = \frac12 + g(x-\frac12)$ where $g$ is any odd function, for example. But there will be lots of such functions, many satisfying the property just by coincidence. Are you restricting to differentiable $f$?

Comment: @GregMartin yes, the graph of y=f(x). Yes, I am restricting to differentiable on [0,1]. I understand that there are many such functions, but I'm looking for a way to classify them, like you did above, or maybe by something like the concavity. This may not be answerable because there could be too many random functions that satisfy this, but I'm just looking for a way to classify the functions that this works for. If it can't be done for every one, so be it, but classes of functions that do work would also be cool, for example all liner functions. Thanks

Comment: @GregMartin I have edited my question to reflect your comments I think.

Comment: I think a complete classification is hopeless. For example: for *any* differentiable function $f_0$ defined on $[0,0.9999]$, there are infinitely many ways to extend it to a differentiable function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ that has the indicated property.

Comment: @GregMartin Even with uniform distribution and the requirement that the function must be continuous everywhere?

Comment: Yes, my examples have both those properties (and all differentiable functions are continuous anyway).

Comment: @GregMartin Okay. If this is not possible, then I guess just giving me some functions for which it will always be true (as you have above) would work. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are going to be infinitely many lines that satisfy the condition. For example, as said above, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}+g(x-\frac{1}{2})$, where g is an odd function.